# How to send the database I created in Postgres to someone?

Tags: postgis, qgis, postgresql-9.5

I made a database using PostgreSQL (using pgAdmin III as the SQL client), and it is filled with shapefiles.

Then i connected that database to Qgis. Now I want to export this database to someone else so they can import it on their PostgreSQL server on their own PC and also get to connect it with Qgis.

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to [create a dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: okay and this will create a .backup file i guess??
So how can the person i'm sending this backup file to import the database on postgresql?

Comment: See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) or [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-copy-database/)